# Nvidia GT 540M Problem, won't install drivers

Tags: nvidia, graphics, installation

I'm new here, and I'm not very good at tech.... So help me here.
The drivers I downloaded from Nvidia's website won't install, even after I boot into TERMINAL ONLY.
After

> sudo gdm stop

It doesn't do anything, but only says

> could not recognize name; bailing out

or something like that.
After I run the nvidia.run driver file, it says I need to remove XServer
HELP PLEASE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GT540M is an NVIDIA Optimus card. Those do not work by default. See also [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)

Now, you shouldn't have installed the drivers from nVidia's website. If you're using a new installation, I recommend doing a clean install. Otherwise, jump into a terminal and run the below command to uninstall the nvidia driver:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA* --uninstall
```

(`NVIDIA*` is actually NVIDIA-Linux-x86*-*.*.run)

To make use of your nvidia card, you could use [Bumblebee](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee). Within a few days, a new stable release should be available. Please do not install it from mj-casalogic/bumblebee PPA as it can break your system.

Comment: Sorry, but can you point me to a tutorial for Bumblebee?
EDIT: Never mind, I've got it. Thanks!

Comment: Please *wait* before installing, you might get issues like having the fans run at full speed or suspend/shutdown issues with the current "stable" version on ppa:mj-casalogic/bumblebee. Follow me (https://twitter.com/Lekensteyn) or https://twitter.com/Team_Bumblebee to get updates. We'll send a message to the linux-hybrid-graphics mailing list too when the release is stable enough and packaged well.

Answer (score 0):

... Go to System Settings, and click on something like "Extra hardware drivers" or "Restricted drivers". It should automatically detect wich driver you need. Just choose it from the list, click the Activate button, and reboot your computer.

Comment: I've tried that, but it only crashes my card.

Comment: Urk, that's strange :p

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to install the proprietary drivers provided by Nvidia for your card. If you are unsure how to do that here is a quick and easy tutorial I found [Easy way to Install Proprietary Drivers in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforum.webs.com/proprietarydrivers.htm)