# Nvidia Driver install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, graphics, asus

I have been searching for days on getting started with Linux and still can't get started.

I am running the following

```
CAELinux xunbuntu 12.04 I7 16 GB ram SSD 500 gb Nvidia GT 540M and an integrated graphics card.
```

I tried to follow the information from this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/12)

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers

sudo apt-get update
```

the following shows up. I don't know if this matters.

```
Note the .com was removed because I can 

W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1396321314
```

then when I try to download the driver....

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree 

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package nvidia-352
```

At this point I tried the manual method from the same site.

but when I typed in

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

I got a

```
"starting the virtual box Guest additions Fail!"
"modprode vboxguest failed"
```

and if I tried to type in my user name and hit enter what I typed just showed up in white text and enter did nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have already reinstalled CAELinux xubuntu 12.04 four times to start fresh.

UPDATE

When I tried to allow the root user access to the X server:

```
xhost local:root
```

And point the command to the right DISPLAY:

```
sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY gedit /etc/profile
```

this was diplayed

```
gedit: command not found
```

I tried

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-352

and after all the update info it displayed

> Unable to locate package nvidia-352

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so CAELinux is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets get Ubuntu to a 'clean' state, without any nvidia drivers installed:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '$2~/nvidia/ {print $2}')
```

Next, let's remove the x-server error - follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175611/cannot-connect-to-x-server-when-running-app-with-sudo/175615#175615) answer.

You can install the latest NVIDIA drivers by adding their new PPA to your system.

To do so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
```

And as OMG! Ubuntu! say: 

**Remember: if the PPA breaks your system you are allowed to keep both halves.** ;)

**NOTE**: The ppa works with versions 12.04.1 through to 15.10, so make sure you upgrade your version to the *.1* release if you haven't already.

**EDIT**:Turns out you can't get the GT540M nvidia drivers to work on Linux.

Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56864/nvidia-gt-540m-problem-wont-install-drivers/56867#56867)  answer.

Comment: Looks like I am using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
On the nvidia website 355 supported products is says "Quadro SDI:

Quadro SDI" Should I be using 352 since I have a GT540M graphics card?

Comment: OMG! Ubuntu! mentions about nvidia-355 "To upgrade to or install the latest Nvidia drivers" - after that, it's up to you

Comment: this is was happened when I tried allow root user access to x-server.                                                                                                                                       
                                 sudo: gedit: command not found.                          I will add the whole thing in a reply

Comment: @DecRobot please see updates to the questions. I am still having issues.

Comment: @BaisJohn Okay, use "nano" instead - terminal text editor

Comment: @BaisJohn I would try using 355, since you can always un-install if it doesn't work...

Comment: I installed gedit and now the terminal opens gedit when I type > sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY gedit /etc/profile but what do I do once it opens? also if I try > sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 I still get  > Unable to locate package nvidia-355. Sorry I am very new to Linux. I appreciate your help a lot. I am struggling.

Comment: @BaisJohn have you added the pa `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`?
`

Comment: Yes, this is was displays after hitting enter the second time .......gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp6jUaqI/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp6jUaqI/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 1118213C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp6jUaqI/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 1118213C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Graphics Drivers Team" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK

Comment: @BaisJohn see my edit

Comment: running this purge command above uninstalls cuda too.. does the install command reinstall it ?

Comment: @Siddharth no...

Answer (score 0):

it is normal if the GPG Key EXPIRE.

Purge your driver and install the "official" ppa driver repository:

http://www.webupd8.org/2015/08/new-official-proprietary-gpu-drivers.html